# Digital Circuit Design Job Market Question Appropriate

Tags: discussion

I have a question regarding the future of Digital Circuit Design/VLSI as layout becomes more automated. I would like insight from professionals in industry, would this be an appropriate question to ask of EE stack exchange?

If not, where can I ask such a question?

Comment: You have sufficient rep to join chat. Click on the link in Nick's answer. All required is a little luck for some people being around.

Comment: You can also try EEVBlog Chat Section, not many rules there.

Answer (score 3):

Resounding **No**.
Career questions are routinely closed as opinion-based.
You can try your question to our [EE.SE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering), where rules are more relaxed.

We appreciate that you have asked in the meta first.

Answer (score 1):

No, that would be primarily opinion based.